# WF4 - Rehosted workflow designer - Localization

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-rehosting

Is there a way to do localization on a rehosted workflow designer? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being the designer part of .NET framework, it is localized when a localized version of .NET framework is installed.